# Looking for a connection string example - SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

Perhaps I'm asking the wrong thing but I cannot find an example of a connection string for SQL Server and Entity Framework. I have such on my local development environment that works fine but when I try to move it to my host (Arvixe) any db i/o fails.

Comment: Someone dings me (-2) for "shows no research etc.". The questions includes the words "cannot find an example". Fyi, I've been looking into this for the last 48 hours (in between being productive otherwise) with no luck so I thought I'd post a definitive question.

Comment: Found the solution after much googling and msdning. My db is named 'YOM' and I had created the entity pieces with same name.  
  
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="YOMEntities"       connectionString="metadata=res://*/IO.YOM.csdl|res://*/IO.YOM.ssdl|res://*/IO.YOM.msl; 
   provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=hazel.arvixe.com;
   Initial Catalog=YOM;User ID=<user id>;Password=<pwd string>;Connection Timeout=60;
   multipleactiveresultsets=true'"    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for this is http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this, too, for a while. It turns out that, yes, there is a difference with connection strings when using EF. The part that was elusive is the metadata stuff, ie, this:

```
"metadata=res://*/IO.YOM.csdl|res://*/IO.YOM.ssdl|res://*/IO.YO‌​M.msl; provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=hazel.arvixe.com;
```

Without that, EF can't find definitions it needs. Btw, without that, it is just a regular sql server connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Arvixe string. Can you hit the database with SSMS?

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=lotus.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=userfromarvixe;Password=pwdfromarvixe" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Yes, I can get to the db with SSMS. I need the connection string specifically for use with entity framework.

Comment: An entity framework connection string is no different. Put it in your web.config and tell your context to use it.

Comment: You need: "metadata=res://*/IO.YOM.csdl|res://*/IO.YOM.ssdl|res://*/IO.YO‌​M.msl;